# Is the definition of gap of a Hamiltonian, i.e. difference between two distinct eigenvalues, restrictive?

Tags: condensed-matter, lattice-model, spin-models

The spectral gap of a quantum model or a Hamiltonian, in the context of whether it is a gapped or gapless model, is often defined as the difference between the two lowest distinct eigenvalues of the Hamiltonian in the thermodynamic limit. **(1)** Is this definition restrictive in the sense that it excludes the case below?

Consider a Hamiltonian in the thermodynamic limit (or even in a finite but large size) has a finite set of distinct eigenvalues below a large spacing characterized by a parameter $\Delta$. That is, its eigenvalues arranged in increasing order are:
$$ \{ \lambda_0,\lambda_1,...,\lambda_n,\lambda_n+\Delta,...\}. $$
Now, suppose that $(\lambda_n-\lambda_0) \ll \Delta$. Can $\Delta$ then be consider a spectral gap for which $\{\lambda_0,...,\lambda_n \}$ corresponds to the groundstate manifold?

**(2)** I would also like to ask if it is important to have the notion of spectral gap tied with the energy associated with local quantum fluctuations. By this I mean, for example, random spin-flip due to quantum fluctuations in spin systems. Suppose $\delta \ll \Delta$ is the energy associated to local quantum fluctuations. Consider $(\lambda_{i+1} - \lambda_i) \leq \delta$ for  $i=0,..,n$. Does this make the model gapless even if the system can only be excited up to the $n$th eigenstate by local quantum fluctuations?

Answer (score 0):

(1) In the thermodynamic limit (TDL), if the eigenvalues $\lambda_0,...,\lambda_n$ are distinct then there is no degeneracy and the gap is viewed as $\lambda_1 - \lambda_0$.
For finite systems, this does not apply, one can have small gaps (due to finite size effects, which may vanish in the TDL). Therefore a gap is essentialy a thermodynamic property. It is a question of whether you have a continuum of modes above your ground state.

(2) Spin-flips are a great example, there are models where a spin-flip 'costs' no energy therefore, $\delta=0$ and this is a gapless mode. However, if there any excitation costs finite amount of energy, your model is gapped.